# Two errors when trying to do pdfteXify in WinEdt 9.1 (same error in TeXWorks) on new laptop

Tags: pdftex, errors, miktex, installing

It seems many people have issues similar to mine, but none of the solutions I found & tried fixed my issues.

I have a new (to me) laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB. I installed the version of WinEdt (9.1) that I had on my old laptop. I downloaded the latest Windows version of MikTeX (MikTeX console 4.5) and installed it. I tried to PDFTeXify a document I've done before on my old laptop, & I got the errors shown below. So I tried it again with the following code, & I got the same errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

> Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf
> --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\clhs_admin\Dropbox\Employment\Test.tex" Startup Folder:
> C:\Users\clhs_admin\Dropbox\Employment
>
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)  restricted \write18 enabled.
>
> Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log
>
> ---
>
> PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)
>
> Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
>
> ---

I tried uninstalling & reinstalling MikTeX, deleting the .FNDB files, comparing the directories with those on my old laptop (there weren't many differences), & restarting the computer. Those are all the suggestions I've found that seem related to my problem. Just for grins I tried to run it in TeXWorks, and I got the same error messages. The two referenced log files are below.

> 2021-12-24 10:24:17,947-0600 INFO  pdflatex - this process (672)
> started by 'texify' with command line: pdflatex
> --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 C:\Users\clhs_admin\Dropbox\Employment\Test.tex 2021-12-24
> 10:24:17,947-0600 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.10.0
> (1.40.24) (MiKTeX 21.12.10) 2021-12-24 10:24:17,963-0600 INFO
> pdflatex - allowing known shell commands 2021-12-24 10:24:18,010-0600
> INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt 2021-12-24
> 10:24:18,010-0600 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf
> --enable-installer --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 ERROR pdflatex -
> C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
> did not succeed; exitCode: 1 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 ERROR
> pdflatex - output: 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 ERROR pdflatex -
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log
>
> 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump
> file could not be found. 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL
> pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt" 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source:
> Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:717 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be
> found. 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex - Info:
> fileName="pdflatex.fmt" 2021-12-24 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex -
> Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,451-0600 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,451-0600 INFO  pdflatex - this process (672) finishes with
> exit code 1

and

> 2021-12-24 10:24:17,651-0600 INFO  texify - this process (7632)
> started by 'WinEdt' with command line: texify.exe --pdf
> --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 C:\Users\clhs_admin\Dropbox\Employment\Test.tex 2021-12-24
> 10:24:17,666-0600 INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex
> --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 C:\Users\clhs_admin\Dropbox\Employment\Test.tex 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL texify.core - TeX engine failed for some
> reason (see log file). 2021-12-24 10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL texify.core
>
> - Data:  2021-12-24 10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1564 2021-12-24 10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL
>   texify - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file). 2021-12-24
>   10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL texify - Info:  2021-12-24 10:24:19,467-0600
>   FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp 2021-12-24
>   10:24:19,467-0600 FATAL texify - Line: 1564

The initexmf.log file contains this:

> 2021-12-24 10:24:18,295-0600 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX
> Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) 2021-12-24
> 10:24:18,295-0600 INFO  initexmf - this process (3400) started by
> 'pdflatex' with command line: initexmf --enable-installer
> --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex 2021-12-24 10:24:18,295-0600 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
> 2021-12-24 10:24:18,310-0600 INFO  initexmf - running:
> miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump
> pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose 2021-12-24 10:24:18,310-0600 INFO  initexmf.core - start process:
> miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump
> pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose 2021-12-24 10:24:19,435-0600 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been
> saved to
> 'C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2021-12-24-102419.out'
> 2021-12-24 10:24:19,435-0600 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did
> not succeed. 2021-12-24 10:24:19,435-0600 FATAL initexmf - Info:
> fileName="C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe",
> exitCode="1" 2021-12-24 10:24:19,435-0600 FATAL initexmf - Source:
> 2021-12-24 10:24:19,435-0600 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0 2021-12-24
> 10:24:19,435-0600 INFO  initexmf - this process (3400) finishes with
> exit code 1

Thank you for helping.

Update: here is the most recent log in makefmt\pdflatex.

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10)
> (INITEX)  24 DEC 2021 11:35 entering extended mode  restricted
> \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled. (cp227.tcx)
> **C:/Users/clhs_admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex
> .ini
>
> (C:/Users/clhs_admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.
> ini
> (C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/config\pdftexconfig.tex
> )
> (C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx
> (C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg)
> \openout15 = `texsys.aux'.
>
> ./texsys.aux found
>
> @currdir set to: ./.
>
> Assuming \openin and \input  have the same search path.
>
> Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.
>
> catcodes, registers, @inputcheck=\read0 @unused=\write0
> \maxdimen=\dimen10 \hideskip=\skip10 \p@=\dimen11 \z@=\dimen12
> \z@skip=\skip11 \voidb@x=\box10  parameters,
> \normalbaselineskip=\skip12 \normallineskip=\skip13
> \normallineskiplimit=\dimen13 \interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
> \strutbox=\box11
>
> LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
>
> (C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx
>
> (C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-cod
> e.tex Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (code)
> \c_max_int=\count24 \l_tmpa_int=\count25 \l_tmpb_int=\count26
> \g_tmpa_int=\count27 \g_tmpb_int=\count28
> \l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29 \l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
> \g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31 \c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
> \c_log_iow=\count33 \l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
> \l__iow_line_target_int=\count35 \l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
> \l__iow_indent_int=\count37 \c_zero_dim=\dimen14 \c_max_dim=\dimen15
> \l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16 \l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17 \g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
> \g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19 \c_zero_skip=\skip14 \c_max_skip=\skip15
> \l_tmpa_skip=\skip16 \l_tmpb_skip=\skip17 \g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
> \g_tmpb_skip=\skip19 \c_zero_muskip=\muskip10 \c_max_muskip=\muskip11
> \l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12 \l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
> \g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14 \g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
> \l_keys_choice_int=\count38 \l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
> \c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20 \g__intarray_font_int=\count40
> \c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41 \c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
> \c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
> \c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
> \c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
> \c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
> \c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
> \c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
> \c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
> \c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count50 \g__fp_array_int=\count51
> \l__fp_array_loop_int=\count52 \g__cctab_allocate_int=\count53
> \l__sort_length_int=\count54 \l__sort_min_int=\count55
> \l__sort_top_int=\count56 \l__sort_max_int=\count57
> \l__sort_true_max_int=\count58 \l__sort_block_int=\count59
> \l__sort_begin_int=\count60 \l__sort_end_int=\count61
> \l__sort_A_int=\count62 \l__sort_B_int=\count63
> \l__sort_C_int=\count64 \c__str_replacement_char_int=\count65
> \l__str_modulo_int=\count66 \l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count67
> \l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count68
> \l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count69 \l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count70
> \l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count71 \l__regex_internal_a_int=\count72
> \l__regex_internal_b_int=\count73 \l__regex_internal_c_int=\count74
> \l__regex_balance_int=\count75 \l__regex_group_level_int=\count76
> \l__regex_mode_int=\count77 \c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count78
> \c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count79 \l__regex_catcodes_int=\count80
> \l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count81
> \c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count82 \c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count83
> \c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count84 \c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count85
> \c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count86 \c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count87
> \l__regex_show_lines_int=\count88 \l__regex_min_state_int=\count89
> \l__regex_max_state_int=\count90 \l__regex_left_state_int=\count91
> \l__regex_right_state_int=\count92
> \l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count93 \l__regex_min_pos_int=\count94
> \l__regex_max_pos_int=\count95 \l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count96
> \l__regex_start_pos_int=\count97 \l__regex_success_pos_int=\count98
> \l__regex_curr_char_int=\count99 \l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count100
> \l__regex_last_char_int=\count101
> \l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count102
> \l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count103
> \l__regex_curr_state_int=\count104 \l__regex_step_int=\count105
> \l__regex_min_thread_int=\count106 \l__regex_max_thread_int=\count107
> \l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count108
> \l__regex_match_count_int=\count109
> \l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count110 \l__regex_submatch_int=\count111
> \l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count112
> \l__regex_added_begin_int=\count113 \l__regex_added_end_int=\count114
> \g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count115 \c_empty_box=\box12
> \l_tmpa_box=\box13 \l_tmpb_box=\box14 \g_tmpa_box=\box15
> \g_tmpb_box=\box16 \l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
> \l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22 \l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
> \l__box_right_dim=\dimen24 \l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
> \l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26 \l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
> \l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28 \l__box_internal_box=\box17
> \l__color_internal_int=\count116 \g__color_model_int=\count117
> \l__coffin_internal_box=\box18 \l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
> \l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30 \l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
> \l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32 \l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
> \l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34 \l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
> \c_empty_coffin=\box19 \l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
> \l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21 \l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
> \l_tmpb_coffin=\box23 \g_tmpa_coffin=\box24 \g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
> \l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
> \l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
> \l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
> \l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
> \l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
> \l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
> \l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42 \c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
> \l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
> \l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
> \l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
> \l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
> \l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44 \l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45
>
> ! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.
>
> For immediate help type H .  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.31110   }
>         !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

Comment: Instead of using texify, does pdflatex work? If not, provide the log from the pdflatex run

Comment: I tried just pdflatex instead of pdftexify, and I got a similar message as before, but with, "Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed." The output in the pdflatex log is exactly the same as when I did pdftexify (and I included that in the original post).

Comment: The actual log (from disk) should not be similar to any of the data you have provided

Comment: miktex couldn't create the format. Find the log and post it, normally it should be the newest file in `C:\Users\clhs_admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex`

Comment: I didn't understand which log you meant, daleif. I posted the one @Ulrike Fischer asked for.

Comment: There should be a log next to your `.tex` file. But do as Ulrike ask, she knows miktex better than most

Comment: Is miktex fully updated?

Comment: Yes, I just downloaded the latest version, checked for updates, and updated all of them. Also, @daleif, there is no log in the same directory as my .tex file, if that's what you meant.

Comment: The "UnicodeData-error" ;-(. Sorry it is quite unknown why it happens on some systems. See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues?q=is%3Aissue+unicodedata.txt.  Perhaps you have some overeager virus protection which prevents miktex to get the file.